# the div background appears white with zooming

Tags: html, css, background

I have an issue with zooming, if any div has background color/border it appears completely white when i zooming in it.

I try zooming in Facebook site and this issue didn't appear.

This image can make the issue more clearly.

[image]

So what is the problem ?

HTML header css

```
header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #BF0404;
  color: white;
  background-position:bottom;
}
```

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: Or even better, an JSFiddle

Comment: I just added the header code

Answer (score 3):

**if problem show once you have an horizontal scrolling bar at bottom of your window**,

then do not use `width:100%` . This is defaut value of block element anyway, it is useless for element kept in the flow;.

`width:100%` will shrink it's layout on screenwidth (or parent if it has a valid width in CSS).

To allow your header to grow beyond parent's width , give it a layout that allows it to naturally expand (or shrink).

```
header {
  min-width:100%;/* as a block element , it should cover all width avalaible, make sure it does */
  display:table;/* will expand , so background will too*/
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLiah/)**

Comment: Thanks, `display: table` fix the problem.

Comment: @MohamedAref, If this answer helped you, accept it then. That way you can give GCyrillus the credits, and the rest of the community wouldn't be bothered with this question anymore

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a fixed width. Try : `width:100%` on your div

Answer (score 0):

necessary to set the width to 100% of the menu

Comment: every parent element take `width:100%`